# How to avoid from InputField TMP ui get affected when the gameplay scene is loading and the screen fade in ? the inputfield is also dark

Tags: unity-game-engine

in the screenshot I toggled to enable and show the InputField tmp in the scene GameNotesScene.

the problem is since the scene is loading while fading in if I enable the InputField while it's in the middle of fading in the InputField is still dark too.  if I will wait for the fade in to finish and then enable the InputField then the InputField will be lighter as it should be.

I tried to add a layer for the canvas and all it's children in the GameNotesScene scene but it didn't solve it.

[image: fade in. in the game view the inputfield and the text inside is very dark because I enabled it while the fade in is in the middle.]

Comment: How are you executing the fade in/out? Is it just a single `Image` on a `Canvas` where its `Color.alpha` changes from 0 to 1? Why can't you layer your `InputField` on top of your fade in/out so it's independent of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm. It's hard to say without seeing exactly what the script is doing, but if the script is not specifically setting the `Color.alpha` of the `InputField`, then one of the following should work:

#### 1. Change the *Child Hierarchy Order* of the `Canvas`'s `GameObject`s

[image]

#### 2. Multiple `Canvas` `GameObject`s with different `Sort Order`s

[image]

Personally, I'd go with the second option; this separates your *fade-in/out* `Canvas`/script from any UI you will need to make.